# Synchronize magento customer table with another mysql table

Tags: magento-1.9, php

How can I synchronize users between two mysql tables using cron job or any other method 
example:
Let's say I have database1.users and magento.customers tables 
I need if any user added or updated from database1.users auto added or updated to magento.customers 
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

> **This Q, belongs to `SQL` not a certain script**

Solution #1:

- create a daemon that checks the `source` table each `xx seconds`
- if there were some data, fetch and insert them into the `destination`
  table

Solution #2:

- using hooks/events
- when there is any data is being inserted in a table, emit an event e.g: `users.add`
- register a new listener for `users.add` to do what you want, and for your case `insert into $onther_table ...`

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**

I don't think this question belongs here, because it's purely `SQL`, nothing specific to Magento.

**General Idea of this**

Yes, you could do a cron job which periodically executes a MYSQL command. The following problems arise:

- what does synchronize mean? which table should be prioritized in case of a conflict? Or do you just want to copy it like a backup?
- if you want to synchronize TO the Magento database as well, you'll have to make sure that it is enough to just add an entry in that table for a user to be added.

Conerning a command to just copy everything to a new table (backup style):

> CREATE TABLE database1.users LIKE magento.customers; INSERT database1.users SELECT * FROM magento.customers;

---

Consider asking this on `stackoverflow`, you're more likely to get more and better answers concerning `SQL` there.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if this solved you problem. Then this doesn't appear as unanswered anymore in the overview